# Getting Null Pointer Excepetion while Using Spark UDFs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I created a Dataframe and wrote a UDF for lowercase to uppercase conversion.

But when I tried calling `nameUdf`, I got `NullPointerException`.

```scala
case class Employee(id:Int, name:String, salary:Double)           
val empList=List("111,aaa,20000.0", "222,bbb,300.00", "333,ccc,4000.00")

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._

val empDF=sc.parallelize(empList).map{line=>
    val data=line.split(",")
    Employee(data(0).toInt,data(1),data(2).toDouble)
}.toDF()

empDF.withColumn("NAME_UP",convert($"name")).show()

val nameUdf=udf{(name:String)=>name.toUpperCase}
val convert=udf[String,String](name=>name.toUpperCase)
```

Exception is shown below:

```
18/03/21 14:08:10 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.org.test.UDFTest$.delayedEndpoint$com$org$test$UDFTest$1(UDFTest.scala:22)
    at com.org.test.UDFTest$delayedInit$body.apply(UDFTest.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.org.test.UDFTest$.main(UDFTest.scala:8)
    at com.org.test.UDFTest.main(UDFTest.scala)
18/03/21 14:08:12 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

How to call the UDF function with the existing dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the `udf` is defined before you use  and `case class` to outside the object scope:

```
object QuickTest extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

  val empList=List("111,aaa,20000.0","222,bbb,300.00","333,ccc,4000.00")

  import spark.implicits._

  val empDF=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(empList).map{line=>
    val data=line.split(",")
    Employee(data(0).toInt,data(1),data(2).toDouble)
  }.toDF()

  val nameUdf=udf{(name:String)=>name.toUpperCase}
  val convert=udf[String,String](name=>name.toUpperCase)

  empDF.withColumn("NAME_UP",convert($"name")).show()
}//end of object QuickTest

case class Employee(id:Int,name:String,salary:Double)
```